# 5*5*5 triple sorting (dependent sorting) based on 3 variables to generate 125 portfolios

Tags: stata

Basically, what I want to do is follow Daniel et al. (1997) to do a 5 * 5 * triple sort (dependent sorting) in CRSP common stock universe. I want to place stocks into a 3-dimensional characteristics space. I want to use a 5*5*5 sorting procedure to classify every potential stock position into quintiles according to three characteristics: market capitalization (ME), book-to-market ratio (BM) and past stock return momentum (Mom).

`yrm`: date variable, e.g. 1998m1,1998m2...

`exchcd`: exchange code, = 1 if the stock is listed on NYSE (New York Stock Exchange)

Step 1: to achieve the first sorting, i.e. sort all stocks (NYSE listed and Non-NYSE listed) based on the NYSE market equity breakpoints:

```
forvalues i = 20(20)80{
    qui bysort yrm: egen ME_Brkp`i' = pctile(ME) if exchcd == 1, p(`i')
}
```

// so obviously, for many non-NYSE listed stocks, has the missing values for all ME breakpoints
//need to assign these NYSE-based breakpoints to those non-NYSE ones too

```
forvalues i = 20(20)80{
    qui by yrm (permno), sort: replace ME_Brkp`i' = ME_Brkp`i'[_n-1] if ME_Brkp`i' >= .
}
if ME_Brkp20 !=. & ME_Brkp40 !=. & ME_Brkp60 !=. & ME_Brkp80 !=. {
qui {
g ME_rank = 1 if ME <= ME_Brkp20 // Smallest Stocks
replace ME_rank = 2 if ME > ME_Brkp20 & ME <= ME_Brkp40
replace ME_rank = 3 if ME > ME_Brkp40 & ME <= ME_Brkp60
replace ME_rank = 4 if ME > ME_Brkp60 & ME <= ME_Brkp80
replace ME_rank = 5 if ME > ME_Brkp80 & ME!=. //Big stocks 
}
}
```

Step 2: Each quintile portfolio is further subdivided into book-to-market quintiles

```
forval r = 1(1)5{
    forvalues i = 20(20)80 { 
        qui bysort yrm ME_rank: egen BM_p`i'_`r' = pctile(cond(ME_rank==`r',BM,.)), p(`i')

    }
}
g BM_rank = .

forval r=1(1)5{
qui {
replace BM_rank = 1 if BM<=BM_p20_`r' & ME_rank== `r' 
replace BM_rank = 2 if BM>BM_p20_`r' & BM<=BM_p40_`r' & ME_rank== `r'
replace BM_rank = 3 if BM>BM_p40_`r' & BM<=BM_p60_`r' & ME_rank== `r'
replace BM_rank = 4 if BM>BM_p60_`r' & BM<=BM_p80_`r' & ME_rank== `r'
replace BM_rank = 5 if BM>BM_p80_`r' & ME_rank== `r' & BM!=. 
}
}
```

Step 3: each of the resulting 25 fractile portfolios is further subdivided into quintiles based on the 12-month past returns of stocks

```
forval mer = 1(1)5{
forval bmr = 1(1)5{
forvalues i = 20(20)80 { 
qui bysort yrm ME_rank BM_rank: egen Mom_p`i'_`mer'_`bmr' = pctile(cond(ME_rank==`mer',BM_rank==`bmr',Mom,.)), p(`i')

}
}
}


g Mom_rank =.
forval mer=1(1)5{
forval bmr=1(1)5{
qui{
replace Mom_rank = 1 if Mom<=Mom_p20_`mer'_`bmr' & ME_rank== `mer' & BM_rank== `bmr' 
replace Mom_rank = 2 if Mom>Mom_p20_`mer'_`bmr' & Mom<=Mom_p40_`mer'_`bmr' & ME_rank== `mer' & BM_rank== `bmr' 
replace Mom_rank = 3 if Mom>Mom_p40_`mer'_`bmr' & Mom<=Mom_p60_`mer'_`bmr' & ME_rank== `mer' & BM_rank== `bmr'
replace Mom_rank = 4 if Mom>Mom_p60_`mer'_`bmr' & Mom<=Mom_p80_`mer'_`bmr' & ME_rank== `mer' & BM_rank== `bmr'
replace Mom_rank = 5 if Mom>Mom_p80_`mer'_`bmr' & ME_rank== `mer' & BM_rank== `bmr' & Mom!=. 
}
}
}
```

Can you identify if there is something wrong with the above codes?
Since when I tab the resulting variables:

```
tab ME_rank
tab BM_rank
tab Mom_rank
```

I got very confusing and suspicious results for the rank based on Mom (Momentum, the past 12 month return):

```
 tab Mom_rank    

  Mom_rank | Freq.   Percent   Cum. 
 ----------+----------------------------------- 
         1 | 1,912,688 93.12  93.12 
         5 |   141,391  6.88 100.00  
 ----------+----------------------------------- 
     Total | 2,054,079 100.00
```

some observations should have `Mom_rank` 2,3, or 4 values. Why does `Mom_rank` only take two values: 1 and 5? And over 90% of them hold value 1?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/957531-5-5-5-triple-sorting-dependent-sorting-based-on-3-variables-to-generate-125-portfolios

Answer (score 0):

A first bug is likely at

```
if ME_Brkp20 !=. & ME_Brkp40 !=. & ME_Brkp60 !=. & ME_Brkp80 !=. {
```

which will look only at the first observation. See

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the `xtile()` function from `egenmore` work for you? Your code seems unnecessarily long and error-prone. See `ssc describe egenmore` to check the description and download it (it is user-written).

An example:

```
clear
set more off

// example data
sysuse auto
replace mpg = . in 2

// display percentiles domestic/foreign (not necessary)
_pctile mpg if foreign, p(20(20)80) 
return list

_pctile mpg if !foreign, p(20(20)80) 
return list

// create groups
egen pct = xtile(mpg), by(foreign) p(20(20)80)
egen pct2 = xtile(mpg), by(foreign pct) p(20(20)80)
egen pct3 = xtile(mpg), by(foreign pct pct2) p(20(20)80)

// list
sort foreign pct pct2 pct3 make
list make mpg foreign pct* in 1/50, sepby(pct pct2 pct3)

// tab
tab pct3
```

Notice that as you progressively nest the percentile categorizations, variability diminishes; but this is expected. If you are categorizing based on different variables (unlike my example), then my guess is variability will depend on the correlation structure of those variables.

Comment: . ssc install egenmore
checking egenmore consistency and verifying not already installed...

the following files already exist and are different:
    c:\ado\plus\_\_gfilter.ado

no files installed or copied
(no action taken)
r(602);

Comment: when I try to install egenmore, error message appears

Comment: Maybe you have a dated version of `egenmore` installed. Check with `help egenmore`. If a help file appears, you already have it. To update see `help adoupdate` and `help ssc`.

Comment: Hi, Roberto, I find it takes much longer for stata to do xtile directly, than using pctile to generate those p20,p40..p80 percentile breakpoints, and then using breakpoints to put those obs into the corresponding quintiles. Another problem is that I need to generate breakpoints (for all stocks in one particular month) by using just the information (market capitalization) of NYSE listed stocks. so if I use the command below: qui bysort yrm:  egen ME_gr = xtile(ME) if exchcd == 1, p(20(20)80) ; I will not get anything that I can use to categorize the non-NYSE listed stocks@Roberto Ferrer

Comment: bysort yrm ME_rank BM_rank: egen Mom_rank = xtile(Mom),  p(20(20)80) 
 I got the error message " 
too many values
r(134);
"

Answer (score 0):

The probelm is:

```
 qui bysort yrm ME_rank BM_rank: egen Mom_p`i'_`mer'_`bmr' = pctile(cond(ME_rank==`mer',BM_rank==`bmr',Mom,.)), p(`i')
```

should be

```
qui bysort yrm ME_rank BM_rank: egen Mom_p`i'_`mer'_`bmr' = pctile(cond(ME_rank==`mer' & BM_rank==`bmr',Mom,.)), p(`i')
```